# Python py2app standalone application using nibabel

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm trying to create an OSx app using py2app.

I used the py2app script without a problem:

```
py2applet --make-setup UltraProcCMD.py
python setup.py py2app
```

This app works fine when I don't use the nibabel package but when I do I get the following error:

```
File "nibabel/__init__.pyc", line 38, in <module>
File "nibabel/analyze.pyc", line 91, in <module>
File "nibabel/wrapstruct.pyc", line 111, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name imageglobals
```

I've tried to explicitly import imageglobals. i.e. in the code:

```
from nibabel import imageglobals
```

This also produces an error in py2app but works fine in a script running in the python interpreter.

Anyone know what I'm missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have a feeling that py2app is not pulling all the dependencies from nibabel that it should. Is there a way to force the entire nibabel package to be included in the py2app?

Comment: Can you import that module via the Python interpreter?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `from nibabel import imageglobals` works fine in the python interpreter but doesn't in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution!

py2app does not seem to import all the required dependencies within the nibabel package, and the nibabel package well known enough to have a custom py2app [recipe](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#recipes).

So using:

```
python setup.py py2app --packages nibabel
```

instead of:

```
python setup.py py2app --packages nibabel
```

seems to force py2app to include the whole nibabel package

Comment: I've added an issue to py2app's tracker about this: <https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/py2app/issue/104/nibabel-issues-when-included-in-py2app> and intend to research why nibabel doesn't work (and might add a recipe for it)

Comment: Thanks Ronald. Your py2app script is brilliant.